# How To fix this Trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have not been able to make this work.

Is it someone who can help me

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `StatusUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `cases` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  
    DECLARE OldStatusText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE NewStatusText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE OldPriorityText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE NewPriorityText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE WorkLogText VARCHAR(256);

    SET WorkLogText = NULL;

    IF NEW.`Status` != OLD.`Status` THEN
        SET OldStatusText = (SELECT `Status` FROM statuses WHERE Id = OLD.`Status`);
        SET NewStatusText = (SELECT `Status` FROM statuses WHERE Id = NEW.`Status`);

        SET WorkLogText = CONCAT("Status changed from '", OldStatusText, "' to '", NewStatusText, "'");
    END IF;

   IF NEW.`Priority` != OLD.`Priority` THEN

        SET OldPriorityText = (SELECT `Priority` FROM priorities WHERE Id = OLD.`Priority`);
        SET NewPriorityText = (SELECT `Priority` FROM priorities WHERE Id = NEW.`Priority`);

      IF WorkLogText IS NOT NULL THEN
            SET WorkLogText = CONCAT("Priority changed from '", OldPriorityText, "' to '", NewPriorityText, "'");
      END IF;
    END IF;

    IF WorkLogText IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO `worklogs` (`CaseId`, `User`, `Text`)
       VALUES
        (
            NEW.Id,
            NEW.LastUser,
            WorkLogText
          );
      END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 27

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem? Are you receiving a syntax error? Is the trigger not firing? Is there some other error? Without knowing the structure of the table and with no knowledge of the data, it may be difficult to offer a solution 

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: What a strange `\"` in your trigger text???

Comment: This error message is mainly caused by a forgotten reassignment of the DELIMITER.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `StatusUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `cases` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 
    DECLARE OldStatusText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE NewStatusText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE OldPriorityText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE NewPriorityText VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE WorkLogText VARCHAR(256);

    SET WorkLogText = NULL;

    IF NEW.`Status` != OLD.`Status` THEN
        SET OldStatusText = (SELECT `Status` FROM statuses WHERE Id = OLD.`Status`);
        SET NewStatusText = (SELECT `Status` FROM statuses WHERE Id = NEW.`Status`);

        SET WorkLogText = CONCAT("Status changed from '", OldStatusText, "' to '", NewStatusText, "'");
    END IF;

   IF NEW.`Priority` != OLD.`Priority` THEN

        SET OldPriorityText = (SELECT `Priority` FROM priorities WHERE Id = OLD.`Priority`);
        SET NewPriorityText = (SELECT `Priority` FROM priorities WHERE Id = NEW.`Priority`);

      IF WorkLogText IS NOT NULL THEN
      SET WorkLogText = CONCAT(WorkLogText, "Priority changed from '", OldPriorityText, "' to '", NewPriorityText, "'" );
   ELSE
            SET WorkLogText = CONCAT( "Priority changed from '", OldPriorityText, "' to '", NewPriorityText, "'" );
      END IF;
    END IF;

    IF WorkLogText IS NOT NULL THEN
      INSERT INTO `worklogs` (`CaseId`, `User`, `Text`)
       VALUES
        (
            NEW.Id,
            NEW.LastUser,
            WorkLogText
          );
      END IF;
     END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What was the problem and what did you change to make it work?